# Function and variables issue

Tags: php

I have a problem.. When I execute this code:

```
public function korisnici(){
    $modelk = new Korisnici();
    $upit = $modelk::find()->asArray()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
    $items = [];
    foreach ($upit as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
            $items[] = [$kljuc => $vrijednost];
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

private static $users = $this->korisnici();
```

It gives me this error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)..

Can someone help me, how can I call this function?

Here's my whole class:

```
class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $authKey;
public $accessToken;
public $arr;

public function korisnici(){
    $modelk = new Korisnici();
    $upit = $modelk::find()->asArray()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
    $items = [];
    foreach ($upit as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
            $items[] = [$kljuc => $vrijednost];
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

public $users = $this->korisnici();

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    foreach (self::$users as $user) {
        if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
            return new static($user);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Finds user by username
 *
 * @param  string      $username
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    foreach (self::$users as $user) {
        if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
            return new static($user);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->authKey;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->authKey === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param  string  $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->password === $password;
}
```

}

I'm trying to change this default model from Yii Framework so I can login using database...

Comment: You can call it from inside another method in the same class or on an object of that class. You cannot initialize a (static or any kind of...) variable like that.

Comment: Can you post an example of that? Because I don't understand how should I do that.. @jeroen

Comment: Well this wouldn't be a very static value don't you thing too?

Comment: @user3002173 Not without a lot more context...

Comment: Can you show us your _entire_ class?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have copied it from a class. The following will work like a regular function. Still not sure where you get `$modelk = new Korisnici();` from

```
function korisnici(){
    $modelk = new Korisnici();
    $upit = $modelk::find()->asArray()->orderBy('id DESC')->all();
    $items = [];
    foreach ($upit as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $kljuc => $vrijednost){
            $items[] = [$kljuc => $vrijednost];
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

print_r(korisnici());
```

EDIT: After looking at your whole class:

You need to use the `__construct` method.

```
public function __construct()
{
 $this->users = $this->korisnici();
}
```

Comment: I got my $modelk = new Korisnici(); from 

use app\models\Korisnici;